# How to create a heat map in python that ranges from green to red?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm trying to plot log ratios from the range -3 to 3 and want negative ratios to be green and positive to be red, with a log ratio of 0 (center) to be white in color. None of the pre-existing color schemes in matplotlib provide this option, and I haven't been able to figure out how to output a nice gradient manually.

Comment: You could settle for an inverted PiYG colormap (green to pink with white in the middle).

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html

Comment: [Beware that](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#color-vision-deficiencies) *"the most common form of color vision deficiency involves differentiating between red and green. Thus, avoiding colormaps with both red and green will avoid many problems in general."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can create your own using a [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap). I like to set the red and green channels to something less than 1.0 at the upper and lower limits so the colours aren't too bright (here I used 0.8). Adjust that to suit your taste.

See the [custom_cmap example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html) on the matplotlib website for further details.

Here's an working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np

# This dictionary defines the colormap
cdict = {'red':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),   # no red at 0
                  (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),   # all channels set to 1.0 at 0.5 to create white
                  (1.0, 0.8, 0.8)),  # set to 0.8 so its not too bright at 1

        'green': ((0.0, 0.8, 0.8),   # set to 0.8 so its not too bright at 0
                  (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),   # all channels set to 1.0 at 0.5 to create white
                  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),  # no green at 1

        'blue':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),   # no blue at 0
                  (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),   # all channels set to 1.0 at 0.5 to create white
                  (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))   # no blue at 1
       }

# Create the colormap using the dictionary
GnRd = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('GnRd', cdict)

# Make a figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Some fake data in the range -3 to 3
dummydata = np.random.rand(5,5)*6.-3.

# Plot the fake data
p=ax.pcolormesh(dummydata,cmap=GnRd,vmin=-3,vmax=3)

# Make a colorbar
fig.colorbar(p,ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I will add that using a green-red colour map is not a great idea as colourblind folks will not be able to interpret your plot!

Comment: Above comment is great advice, quoting [matplotplib’s colormaps documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) : *"The most common form of color vision deficiency involves differentiating between red and green. Thus, avoiding colormaps with both red and green will avoid many problems in general."*

Answer (score 49):

Using [`matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html)'s [`from_list`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) method seems more intuitive than some of the other answers here.

```
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',["r", "w", "g"], N=256)
```

[image]

Or for more sophisticated tuning:

```
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
c = ["darkred","red","lightcoral","white", "palegreen","green","darkgreen"]
v = [0,.15,.4,.5,0.6,.9,1.]
l = list(zip(v,c))
cmap=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',l, N=256)
```

[image]

Comment: It feels like this should be the accepted answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: What command did you use to get this visualization of the colormap ?

Comment: For Ukraine I found the yellow-blue cmap. c2 = ["darkblue","blue","#AAAAFF","white", "#FFFF99", "#FFFF88","yellow"]
v2 = [0,.15,.4,.5,0.53,.9,1.]
yb = list(zip(v2,c2))       After you create the cmap, you can use cmap.reversed(). For example for a correlation matrix (sns.heatmap(df.corr()) the yellow is above with the first setup not the reversed one.

Answer (score 5):

How about the following that uses [`LinearSegmentedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


cmapGR = LinearSegmentedColormap(
    'GreenRed',
    {
        'red':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
        'green':((0.0, 1.0, 1.0),
                (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                ( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                (0.5, 1.0, 1.0),
                (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    },)

plt.imshow(np.array([np.arange(200) for i in range(200)]), cmap=cmapGR)
plt.show()
```

It produces the following [image]

See e.g. http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html for more uses and other examples.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly red to green, but there's a diverging colormap: RdYlGn, red-yellow-green.

```
plot = sns.heatmap(df.corr().round(2),cmap='RdYlGn',annot=True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to use `g` or `r` because these are different than the default `Greens` and `Reds` Colormaps https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html

So I concatenate Greens and Reds.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np

sample = 15
colors = np.vstack(
    (
        # Default is White -> Green but I want Green -> White -> Red so reverse the order
        plt.get_cmap("Greens", sample)(np.linspace(0, 1, sample))[::-1],
        # np.ones((1, 4)),  # Explicit White optional
        plt.get_cmap("Reds", sample)(np.linspace(0, 1, sample)),
    )
)
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("green_to_red", colors)
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 1), tight_layout=True)
ax.imshow(np.array([np.arange(256) for i in range(256)]), cmap="Greens", aspect="auto")
fig.show()
```

[image]

And a Scatter Plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), tight_layout=True)
x = np.linspace(-7, 7, 1000)
map = ax.scatter(x, np.cos(x), c=y, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(mappable=map, ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

[image]