# How to visualize indivisual channels of image in LAB color space in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, opencv

I am having some trouble with finding documentation of visualization of LAB color space in `matplotlib`. I got the channels separated. Here is my code for that:

```py
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
img_LAB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l,a,b = cv2.split(img_LAB)
```

I don't have any problems with displaying the L channel as it is just grayscale.

```py
plt.imshow(l,cmap='gray')
```

however I cannot find any colormaps for a and b. "a" is red-green and "b" is blue-yellow and matplotlib doesn't have cmap option for them. If I try to directly `imshow` the channels, it gives RGB image. I tried creating a red-green channel. don't know if this is correct:

```py
cdict1 = {'red':   ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    (0.5, 0.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0, 0.1, 1.0)),

          'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),

          'green':  ((0.0, 0.0, 0.1),
                    (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
                    (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
          }
red_green = LinearSegmentedColormap("RdGn",cdict1)
```

I am also having confusion regarding the cmap dict. what does the two y values signify? the documentations do have clear explanation. I don't know if my cmap is correct. But I still don't get how to display b channel. What can be the better way of doing this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246559/how-to-create-a-heat-map-in-python-that-ranges-from-green-to-red/38247002#38247002) shows how you can create a red-green colormap. you could do something similar for blue-yellow (see also the `cividis` colormap which ranges from blue to yellow.)

Comment: @tmdavison I think that helps, but I am having confusion understanding the dictionary. what does X, i.e. the first element of the tuple signify? also, if 0.8 on both means less bright, what will y = 0,0.8 or .8,0 mean?

Comment: I tried explaining it as best I can in that answer. If that's still not clear, perhaps you could try the `from_list` method in the answer below on that question.